# How to remove the "new carpet smell" (VOCs) from new carpet?

Tags: carpet

My wife is pregnant. We just had new carpet installed in the soon to be baby's room. We didn't realize until after it was installed that the "new carpet smell" is actually a bad thing. From what I've read online, new carpet gives off harmful fumes, which contain VOCs, for months.

What can I do to expedite the process of removing these harmful VOCs and air out the carpet?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how true it is but I've heard a few times that certain plants do a good job of removing VOCs from household air. You could try investigating this claim. Here's one page that mentions it.

http://www.thedailygreen.com/going-green/tips/best-plants-for-indoor-air-quality

My wife has trouble with a variety of VOCs. It might not be an option for you to store the carpet partially outstretched in your garage until most of the odour departs.

Comment: It has already been installed, so unfortunately I cannot store it in the garage.

Comment: @Andrew - It's actually pretty easy to pull up a non-glued carpet and then put it back later. Back when we foolishly used to put carpet in our rentals, I used to take them in the back yard for ease of cleaning.

Answer (score 1):

A small window fan can be used to ventilate the room with fresh air.  You should be able to find one that can be set to blow the air out the window rather than into the rest of the house.

Answer (score 1):

While it's been several years since the original post, there are now some air purifying paints on the market that might be useful for people to know about to help combat offgassing from rugs, furniture, etc. I have used ECOS Paints Interior Atmosphere Purifying Paint for my walls and ceilings (not for humid location application). It claims to absorb 98% to 99% of VOCs down to 1 ppm. MSDS available on the ECOS Paints website. There are also plug in HEPA air purifiers, of course, but we loved the idea that our paint (of all things) could help improve air quality.

Answer (score 0):

It will take some time for the VOC's to off-gas.  Ventilation is one of the best things you can do. So, open the windows to allow the outside air to mix in even if cold outside.

Another option is to put an air purifier with a lot of [activated carbon](http://www.air-purifier-ratings.org/how_carbon_works.html) to absorb the VOC gases.  It will likely take weeks to months for the VOC level to go down and if you can't properly ventilate the carbon will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I got a mens roll on deodorant (old spices) , remember not the aerosol one.
I remove the gelly substance and immersed in a plastic container filled with hot water and poured the liquid in the electric Steam Iron and turn on steam and Ironed every corner like I press my cloths slowly so that heat is penetrated and kept windows and ventilations on so that I do not breath the VOC's.
Then vacuumed and thrower some agarbatti around room so I am occupied with smell I appreciate(Incense sticks).

The weather is cold outside but its better than suffocating smell.
Let me know if you find any other ways.

I feel best is to ventilate and make the poisonous VOC's diluted and cause much less harm.